# Create a table from a function's return values

Tags: python

I have this;

```
import operator
cuts = { "Emerald" : (10,125),
         "Oval" : (20,150),
         "Pear" : (35, 175),
         "Plumbbob" : (50,200),
         "Marquis" : (75, 230),
         "Crystal Ball" : (100, 260),
         "Brilliant" : (250, 350),
         "Star Cut" : (400,400),
         "Heart-shaped" : (1000, 500)
         }

def best(amount):
    "Returns most profitable cut's name."
    max_name = ""
    max_value = -10000
    for k,v in cuts.iteritems():
        value = ((float(amount) * (v[1] - 100) / 100)) - v[0]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_name = k
    return max_name

def create_table():
    """Creates a table like

       0-40 emerald
       40-45 Oval
       ...
       2000 + Heart-shaped
    """
```

But I am stuck at writing `create_table`. This code is for helping with a game I am playing. `best` funciton, given an amount, returns most profitable cut name for that amount. I want to create a table that shows me ranges. For example, for amounts between 0-40, best cut is emerald, between 40-45 best cut is Oval etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create_table():
    curname = None
    for amount in xrange(2500):
        name = best(amount)
        if name != curname:
            if curname is not None:
                print "%d-%d %s" % (minamt, amount-1, curname)
            curname = name
            minamt = amount
    print "%d-%d %s" % (minamt, amount-1, curname)
```

(not tested, btw)

Answer (score 1):

An analytic solution is undoubtedly overkill... but hey, I like overkill.

First, I transformed `cuts` into y=mx+b format:

```
cuts = [(k, (v1-100)*0.01,-v0) for k,(v0,v1) in cuts.items()]
cuts.sort()
```

resulting in

```
cuts = [
    ('Brilliant',       2.5,    -250),
    ('Crystal Ball',    1.6,    -100),
    ('Emerald',         0.25,    -10),
    ('Heart-shaped',    4.0,   -1000),
    ('Marquis',         1.3,     -75),
    ('Oval',            0.5,     -20),
    ('Pear',            0.75,    -35),
    ('Plumbbob',        1.0,     -50),
    ('Star Cut',        3.0,    -400)
]
```

For each pair of cuts, I can find the intersection-point - the gem size at which the value of either cut is the same

```
from itertools import combinations

xints = []
for (na,ma,ba),(nb,mb,bb) in combinations(cuts, 2):
    xint = (bb-ba)/(ma-mb)
    val = ma*xint + ba

    # figure out which cut dominates to the right
    va = ma*(xint+0.01)+ba
    vb = mb*(xint+0.01)+bb
    if vb > va:
        xints.append((xint,val,na,nb))
    else:
        xints.append((xint,val,nb,na))
```

This results in 36 intersections, most of which are redundant - some other cut is more valuable at that point. So we filter:

```
xints = [(xint,val,na,nb) for xint,val,na,nb in xints if all(nc==na or nc==nb or mc*xint+bc <= val for nc,mc,bc in cuts)]
xints.sort()
```

which leaves 10 valid intersections:

```
[
    (40.0, 0.0, 'Emerald', 'Oval'),
    (60.0, 10.0, 'Oval', 'Pear'),
    (60.0, 10.0, 'Oval', 'Plumbbob'),
    (60.0, 10.0, 'Pear', 'Plumbbob'),
    (83.33333333333331, 33.333333333333314, 'Marquis', 'Crystal Ball'),
    (83.33333333333331, 33.333333333333314, 'Plumbbob', 'Crystal Ball'),
    (83.33333333333331, 33.333333333333314, 'Plumbbob', 'Marquis'),
    (166.66666666666669, 166.66666666666674, 'Crystal Ball', 'Brilliant'),
    (300.0, 500.0, 'Brilliant', 'Star Cut'),
    (600.0, 1400.0, 'Star Cut', 'Heart-shaped')
]
```

By inspection we see that Pear and Marquis cuts are redundant - they are competitive only exactly at the intersection points - so we discard the 4 items in which they appear, getting

```
[
    (40.0, 0.0, 'Emerald', 'Oval'),
    (60.0, 10.0, 'Oval', 'Plumbbob'),
    (83.33333333333331, 33.333333333333314, 'Plumbbob', 'Crystal Ball'),
    (166.66666666666669, 166.66666666666674, 'Crystal Ball', 'Brilliant'),
    (300.0, 500.0, 'Brilliant', 'Star Cut'),
    (600.0, 1400.0, 'Star Cut', 'Heart-shaped')
]
```

which are the optimal intersections; then your table ends up looking like

```
Size      Value      Cut
----      -----     ------------
   0       -10
                    Emerald
  40         0
                    Oval
  60        10
                    Plumbbob
  83.33     33.33
                    Crystal Ball
 166.67    166.67
                    Brilliant
 300       500
                    Star Cut
 600      1400
                    Heart-shaped
```

and strictly speaking you can probably discard Emerald-cut, as the expected values are negative (making a cut on any gem smaller than 40 loses you money).